# A python program that rolls two dice and count the attempt until both the number of these dices are 6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written these code but it does not work.

```
import random

count=0

while True:
    x=random.randint(1,6)
    y=random.randint(1,6)
    print(x,y)

    if x!=6 and y!=6:
        count+=1
    else:
        print('Attempt number is {}.'.format(count))
        break



However, I have nonsense outputs such as : 6 2 
                                        Attempt number is 0.
```

Also, could you please write this code by using functions if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def guess_count():
    count=0
    x,y=0,0
    while True:
        if x==6 and y==6:
            print('Attempt number is {}.'.format(count))
            break
        x=random.randint(1,6)
        y=random.randint(1,6)
        print(x,y)
        count+=1
guess_count()
```

Hopefully this will work according to your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need a separate function:

```
import random

def check():
    count = 0
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1,6)
        y = random.randint(1,6)
        print(x,y)
        if x==6 and y==6:
            break
        else:
            count+=1
    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = check()
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You code breaks if either the value of x, or y is 6**.

The following condition fails only when either of the value is 6.

```
if x!=6 and y!=6:
```

Then, the else part is executed.

```
else:
        print('Attempt number is {}.'.format(count))
        break
```

and attempt number is displayed.

You can do it **using function** as follows:

```
import random

def exit_if_6(x, y, count ):
    print(x,y)
    if x!=6 and y!=6:
        count+=1
    else:
        print('Attempt number is {}.'.format(count))
    return count

while True:
    a = input("Press 0 to exit !")
    count = 0
    if a:
        x=random.randint(1,6)
        y=random.randint(1,6)

        count = exit_if_6(x, y, count)
```

You can optionally change the while loop to make **custom input** like this:

```
while True:
    a = input("Press 0 to exit !")
    count = 0
    if a:
        x = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        y = int(input("Enter second number: "))

        count = exit_if_6(x, y, count)
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed this point. Now it works. Finally, is there any way to write it by using functions?

Comment: I have added a version using a function in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for 6-6 which will make it easier to code and read:

```py
import random

count=0

while True:
    x=random.randint(1,6)
    y=random.randint(1,6)
    count+=1 # we rolled the dice, so we increment the counter
    print('attempt:',count, '- Got these:',x,y)

    if x == 6 and y == 6:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you got the answer for your mistake, I structured your code to make use of functions too.

```
import random

count=0

def rollDice():
    #use count as global statement to reference it in the function
    global count   
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    y = random.randint(1,6)
    count+=1 #increment count once die are rolled 
    print(x,y) 
    return x,y 


while True:
    x,y = rollDice();
    if x==6 and y==6:
        print('Attempt number is {}.'.format(count))
        break
```

Comment: Why `global`? You could do `return count, x, y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

count=0

while True:
    x=random.randint(1,6)
    y=random.randint(1,6)
    print(x,y)

    if x!=6 or y!=6:
        count+=1
    else:
        print('Attempt number is {}.'.format(count))
        break
```

Now it will work